# AngularJS: ng-repeat the list but with titles and grouped by

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, list, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have

```
myCtrl.guests = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"},
    {"firstName":"Albert", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Mark", "lastName":"Jones"},
    {"firstName":"Mark", "lastName":"Smith"}
];
```

and it is perfectly displayed on the page with

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="guest in guests">
            {{guest.firstName}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

As result, 6 persons displayed in the list.

**However**, I need to group this list by the last names so that the list  on the page looks like this (6 persons with 3 last names = 9 ):

```
    <ul>
        <li class="title">
            Doe
        </li>
        <li>
            John
        </li>
        <li class="title">
            Jones
        </li>
        <li>
            Peter
        </li>
        <li>
            Mark
        </li>
        <li class="title">
            Smith
        </li>
        <li>
            Anna
        </li>
        <li>
            Albert
        </li>
        <li>
            Mark
        </li>
    </ul>
```

`class="title"` above will help **to highlight the last names** and apply css styles for last names appropriately.
Any ideas how to make it with AngularJS? I guess it should be somehow short and nice.

Comment: Create a function which generates the desired JSON and them consume that JSON to display it

Comment: Do you have trouble aligning the result as you like. You have the data already with you, just that you will have to play with the HTML on how to display as lastname followed by firstname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to check this fiddle link as it is an angular directive to group and show the grouped result

http://jsfiddle.net/4Dpzj/6/

```
<div ng-repeat="item in MyList  | orderBy:'groupfield' | groupBy:['groupfield']">
```